# Comparing strings with != operator giving different results?

Tags: c#, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I know this might sound like a very stupid question but I'm out of answers on this one. One of our users reported a bug recently and I realized that an old bit of code was using `!= string.Empty` rather that `IsNullOrEmpty()`. I fixed it with `IsNullOrEmpty()` and it now runs fine, but I'd like to actually understand the problem

The thing is, the exact same bit of code runs differently on certain machines. I basically have an object: `context["MODE"]`, that is supposed to be empty. I added some tests on it to log:

```
        contextBuilder.AppendLine("MODE: |" + context["MODE"] + "|");
        contextBuilder.AppendLine("MODE != string.Empty: " + (context["MODE"] != string.Empty));
        contextBuilder.AppendLine("MODE TRIM != string.Empty: " + (context["MODE"].ToString().Trim() != string.Empty));
        contextBuilder.AppendLine("MODE.IsNullOrEmpty: " + string.IsNullOrEmpty(context["MODE"].ToString()));
        contextBuilder.AppendLine("MODE.TRIM.IsNullOrEmpty: " + string.IsNullOrEmpty(context["MODE"].ToString().Trim()));
```

Here are my logs about that field details:

```
MODE: || 
MODE != string.Empty: False  
MODE TRIM != string.Empty: False 
MODE.IsNullOrEmpty: True  
MODE.TRIM.IsNullOrEmpty: True
```

Here are his logs:

```
MODE: ||
MODE != string.Empty: True
MODE TRIM != string.Empty: False
MODE.IsNullOrEmpty: True
MODE.TRIM.IsNullOrEmpty: True
```

As you can see there is one difference: `MODE != string.Empty` is False for me (makes sense), True for him! MODE is obviously not null (otherwise `.ToString()` would have failed) The problem is fixed by using IsNullOrEmpty but I'm trying to figure out exactly why would this not work on certain user's machines and not others. Typically with my tests some of us had no problems, other had.

I don't really understand what can I learn about it. Why is his mode different than null and `String.Empty`, but `IsNullOrEmpty` returns true? Also note that the trim is actually `string.Empty` as well

Thank you!

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty` actually does the empty part by comparing the `Length` to 0.

Comment: Try also printing out `context["Mode"].GetType().Name` as well.

Comment: Can you provide more detail regarding the origin of the value in `context["MODE"]`? Also, have you ensured the versions of .NET are the same on both machines?

Comment: `context["MODE"]` is a `string` boxed in `object` in both cases. And yes both machines run the same .NET framework!

Answer (score 4):

If you use `ToString()`, that's an indication that the type of `context["MODE"]` is `object`. If you compare an object with a string using `!=`, you're comparing string references, not the actual string values.

So "his mode" is an empty string that is not the same reference as `string.Empty`.

Don't use reference comparisons on strings; always ensure both sides are of type `string` before using `==` or `!=`.

Note that the C# compiler should have warned you about this: [CS0252: Possible unintended reference comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6dtw2ah.aspx)

Comment: @clcto That's the correct output, because not equal to `String.Empty` returned false, meaning that it _is_ equal to `String.Empty`

Comment: As I said this was an old bit of code, written by the guy who was taking care of the app before I joined the company here (and yup, there was a warning he missed!). I'm rather wondering here why are his results this way? His input is empty, but not having the same reference as `string.Empty`. However when I Trim it it has the same reference! How would this possibly happen?

Comment: The return type of `Trim()` is `string`, so the compiler uses a value comparison in that case.